# GridViewComboBoxColumns get NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, combobox, nullreferenceexception

I have a `ComboBoxColumn` in a `DataGridView`. When I single click on it, then move to the next or previous rows in the same Column I get an `Exception` (and my application crashes).

Here is my code, how do I solve this?

```
private void cmbBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // dgv_Panchang.EndEdit();
        string SpID = string.Empty;
        //ComboBox cmbBox = (ComboBox)sender;
        ComboBox cmbBox = new ComboBox();
        cmbBox = (ComboBox)sender;
        if (cmbBox != null)
        {

            if (dgv_Panchang.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
                Cls_Global_Var.Name = string.Empty;
                Cls_Global_Var.Name = cmbBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                if (Cls_Global_Var.Name != string.Empty)
                {
                    Cls_Global_Var.StrSql = string.Empty;
                    Cls_Global_Var.StrSql = "select Pk_SpecialDay from    tbl_specialday where V_Title ='" + Cls_Global_Var.Name + "'";

                    SpID = Cls_DataBase.GetIdentCurrentID(Cls_Global_Var.StrSql);

                    if (SpID != null)
                    {
                        int RowIndex = dgv_Panchang.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                        int ColIndex = dgv_Panchang.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                        DataGridViewCell dgvCurrent = dgv_Panchang[ColIndex + 2, RowIndex];
                        if (dgvCurrent != null)
                        {
                            dgv_Panchang.CurrentCell = dgvCurrent;
                            dgv_Panchang.CurrentRow.Cells["SPDValue"].Value = SpID;

                            Cls_PanchangMaster_Obj.GetSpecialDayName(Convert.ToInt32(SpID), ColIndex, dgv_Panchang);
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            else if (dgv_Panchang.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4)
            {
                try
                {
                    Cls_Global_Var.Name = string.Empty;
                    Cls_Global_Var.Name = cmbBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    if (Cls_Global_Var.Name != string.Empty && Cls_Global_Var.Name != null)
                    {
                        Cls_Global_Var.StrSql = string.Empty;
                        Cls_Global_Var.StrSql = "select Pk_SpecialDay from  tbl_specialday where V_Title ='" + Cls_Global_Var.Name + "'";

                        SpID = Cls_DataBase.GetIdentCurrentID(Cls_Global_Var.StrSql);
                        if (SpID != null)
                        {
                            int RowIndex = dgv_Panchang.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                            int ColIndex = dgv_Panchang.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                            DataGridViewCell dgvCurrent = dgv_Panchang[ColIndex + 2, RowIndex];
                            if (dgvCurrent != null)
                            {
                                dgv_Panchang.CurrentCell = dgvCurrent;
                                dgv_Panchang.CurrentRow.Cells["SPDValue"].Value = SpID;

                                Cls_PanchangMaster_Obj.GetSpecialDayName(Convert.ToInt32(SpID), ColIndex, dgv_Panchang);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Cls_GlobalMessage.CreatErrorLog(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Cls_GlobalMessage.CreatErrorLog(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        dgv_Panchang.ClearSelection();
        dgv_Panchang.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception you're getting, and on which line?

Answer (score 1):

This question is poorly asked and is unlikely to bring you a response that will solve your problem.  Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for general guidelines on how to ask coding questions.  The more work you put into the question, the more work answerers are likely to put into answering your question.  With the amount of information provided thus far, the best we can give you is that the exception is probably because you're using the `.` operator on a variable with a null value. Useful right ;-)

**That being said**, there are several other steps you can take to clean up your code a bit.  Let's start at the first try catch finally.  You are dereferencing `dgv_Panchang` in many places including your finally block.  Are you sure that `dgv_Panchang` is never null?  if it is null, you could get a `NullReferenceException`.  Also, it looks like both of your catch blocks do the same thing.  You can probably remove the inner try-catch without changing any semantics of your code (the stacktrace might have a different line number for caught exceptions)

Moving on.  In many places, you are setting variables to a new object and then immediately setting it to something different: ie

```
ComboBox cmbBox = new ComboBox();
cmbBox = (ComboBox)sender;

Cls_Global_Var.Name = string.Empty;
Cls_Global_Var.Name = cmbBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

Cls_Global_Var.StrSql = string.Empty;
Cls_Global_Var.StrSql = "select Pk_SpecialDay from    tbl_specialday where V_Title ='" + Cls_Global_Var.Name + "'";
```

The first line can be removed in all of these instances to save time and memory.  This isn't wrong, but is merely a code review suggestion.

It appears you are using a few static global classes for storing information such as `Cls_Global_Var.Name` or `Cls_Global_Var.StrSql`.  There are probably better ways to handle this without statics, and if you also have to be careful of multi-threaded issues if applicable, but that's too big of an issue and requires more context than what you have given here to discuss.

The code for when `dgv_Panchang.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1` and when it is `4` are very similar.  Except for the additional try-catch in the later which, as I previously mentioned, probably isn't needed, the only difference is in the extra clause in the if statement:

```
Cls_Global_Var.Name = cmbBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
if (Cls_Global_Var.Name != string.Empty && Cls_Global_Var.Name != null)
```

Since `.ToString()` will never return null, the `&& Cls_Global_Var.Name != null` isn't needed and can be removed. (as a side note, look into `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`)

Once you remove that, the two code blocks are the same meaning you can condense your if statement with something like:

`if (dgv_Panchang.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 || dgv_Panchang.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4)`

Shortening LOC count like this is a Good Thing.

One more critique:  I hope your comboBox doesn't allow raw user input, lest he enter something like `"';DROP TABLE tbl_specialday;--"` or worse and ruin your day.  Look into SQL parameters to make your code more robust.